# Poky-tiny issue for qemuarm with systemd

Tags: linux, arm, kernel, yocto, qemu

I am trying to make a build for qemuarm with DISTRO poky-tiny. I also need systemd as init manager.
**Qemu works successfully with qemux86-64, why it doesn't work for qemuarm?**
**Qemuarm works successfully with sysvinit, why it doesn't work with systemd?**
Here is my local.conf file

```bash
DISTRO ?= 'poky-tiny'
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= 'package_rpm'
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks"
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats"
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"
BB_DISKMON_DIRS ??= "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    HALT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    HALT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    HALT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    HALT,/tmp,10M,1K"
PACKAGECONFIG:append:pn-qemu-system-native = " sdl"
CONF_VERSION = "2"

require ../../conf/git-describe.inc
MANIFEST_VERSION := "${@git_describe(d.getVar("BSPDIR"), d.getVar("DISTRO"))}"

CONNECTIVITY_CHECK_URIS = ""


INHERIT += "rm_work"
MACHINE = "qemuarmv5"

#PACKAGECONFIG:append:pn-systemd = " networkd"
INITRAMFS_MAXSIZE = "200000"
#INHERIT+="toaster buildhistory"
ACCEPT_FSL_EULA = "1"

# use systemd as the default init manager
DISTRO_FEATURES:append = "systemd"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED += "sysvinit"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "busybox"
#VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = "initscripts"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_login_manager = "busybox"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = "systemd-compat-units"
KERNEL_FEATURES:append = " cfg/systemd.scc"
```

Qemu doesn't run, here are the logs

```bash
[    5.829313] workingset: timestamp_bits=30 max_order=16 bucket_order=0
[    5.883554] brd: module loaded
[    5.899423] rtc-pl031 9010000.pl031: registered as rtc0
[    5.901240] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    5.901537] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    5.903321] NET: Registered PF_PACKET protocol family
[    5.904744] NET: Registered PF_VSOCK protocol family
[    5.906121] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    6.383892] printk: console [netcon0] enabled
[    6.384189] netconsole: network logging started
[    6.452892] IP-Config: Complete:
[    6.453157]      device=eth0, hwaddr=52:54:00:12:34:08, ipaddr=192.168.7.8, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=192.168.7.7
[    6.453934]      host=192.168.7.8, domain=, nis-domain=(none)
[    6.454198]      bootserver=255.255.255.255, rootserver=255.255.255.255, rootpath=
[    6.454287]      nameserver0=8.8.8.8
[    6.462345] uart-pl011 9000000.pl011: no DMA platform data
[    6.513454] Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 196K
[    6.513771] Kernel memory protection not selected by kernel config.
[    6.514395] Run /init as init process
init started: BusyBox v1.35.0 ()
starting pid 108, tty '': '/bin/mount -t proc proc /proc'
starting pid 109, tty '': '/bin/mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys'
starting pid 110, tty '': '/bin/mount -t devtmpfs devtmpfs /dev'
starting pid 111, tty '': '/bin/mount -o remount,rw /'
starting pid 112, tty '': '/bin/mkdir -p /dev/pts'
starting pid 113, tty '': '/bin/mount -t devpts devpts /dev/pts'
starting pid 114, tty '': '/bin/mount -a'
starting pid 115, tty '': '/sbin/swapon -a'
starting pid 121, tty '': '/etc/init.d/rcS'
can't run '/etc/init.d/rcS': No such file or directory
starting pid 122, tty '/dev/ttyAMA0': '/sbin/getty 115200 ttyAMA0'
can't open /dev/hvc0: No such file or directory
process '/sbin/getty 115200 hvc0' (pid 123) exited. Scheduling for restart.
can't open /dev/hvc0: No such file or directory
process '/sbin/getty 115200 hvc0' (pid 125) exited. Scheduling for restart.
can't open /dev/hvc0: No such file or directory
process '/sbin/getty 115200 hvc0' (pid 126) exited. Scheduling for restart.
can't open /dev/hvc0: No such file or directory
process '/sbin/getty 115200 hvc0' (pid 127) exited. Scheduling for restart.
```

Can anyone tell me what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

after it has successfully connected to /dev/ttyAMA0 at 115200, then it is trying to find a virtual console hvc0. There should be only one console that is tty AMA0; just remove hvc0 from the qemuarm command.